# Symbolic links error while creating Ubuntu UEFI bootable USB

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

I have tried to create UEFI bootable USB drive within Ubuntu 14.10 (Startup disk creator didn't help nor I am interested in using it.).
I have formated USB with FAT32 and GPT. So the only thing left to do would be just to copy all files from ISO to USB. That method worked when it comes to Linux Mint 17.1 and Clonezilla live CD, but when I tried to create bootable USB for Ubuntu 14.04 or Kubuntu 15.04 beta 1 there was an error copying files. Actually, on several occasions (4 or 5) pop-up window appeared.
[image]

After ignoring this errors, both Ubuntu and Kubuntu USB boot-up just fine, with no apparent problems in Live mode.

1. Can someone please elaborate what this symbolic links presents?
2. Will this cause some problem when OS is installed?

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases so Mint is off-topic here as well.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. It was mentioned so people can get a better insight of the problem, since it is based on Ubuntu.

Comment: I understand, but the question and answer will still be closed as off-topic as it *is off-topic*...

Comment: I got an error trying to create a bootable Ubuntu USB from Ubuntu. How's that off-topic? How acn people use Ubuntu if they cannot install it?

Comment: Well I'm glad it wasn't closed as off-topic because that would've been literally absurd. The problem clearly has to do with Ubuntu, simply referencing the fact that other distributions exist isn't illegal here.

Comment: This is extremely useful and should not be closed. You get the same error trying to do this for Ubuntu 22.04 too.

Answer (score 4):

You can find symbolic links with the `-type l` option to `find`. I don't happen to have a 15.04 beta CD image handy, but I do have a 14.10 image, and I ran the command against it:

```
$ find /mnt/cdrom -type l 
/mnt/cdrom/dists/stable
/mnt/cdrom/dists/unstable
/mnt/cdrom/ubuntu
```

Those are all the symbolic links on the image file. I can't say I know precisely why they're there. If you can install from a medium that lacks these links, though, chances are everything will be fine and there will be no long-lasting problems caused by the fact that your installation medium lacks these links.

One more point: My preferred method of creating a Linux installation medium is to use `dd`, thus:

```
sudo dd if=imagefile.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

Change the `if=` and `of=` values as necessary. The resulting disk is something of a Frankenstein's monster in terms of its partitioning and related data structures, but it does work.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why are this links on ISO in the first place since Mint doesn't have them and FAT32 doesn't support them. It is likely that there will be no problems,still...USB can be created from the Disk image writer as well, but it also ruins it's partition style which I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Does `dd`  also create a UEFI only installer please? I'm trying to follow point 2 in this guide and get the symbolic link error: https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media/