# Is it really possible to properly create a bootable USB of Ubuntu from Windows?

Tags: boot, usb, symbolic-link, fat32

I was trying to create a bootable USB of Ubuntu from Ubuntu when some symbolic links errors appeared, which I explained in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599516/symbolic-links-error-while-creating-ubuntu-uefi-bootable-usb). There was no valid answer what these errors are, nor are they significant. It is possible to bypass them using  *Disk image writer*  which came preinstalled in Ubuntu. However, symbolic links are not compatible with FAT32 filesystem and the reason why Disk image writer can bypass these is because (I believe) it rearrange filesystem on USB.

[image]

Now, I don't think there is a single tool for Windows that can do this rearrange, so this links are not included in a bootable USB. Hence the question:

Is it really possible to properly create a bootable USB of Ubuntu from Windows?

Comment: Im not sure exactly what you mean, do you just want to make a bootable usb in windows http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ Or something more ?

Comment: Yes, but to include symbolic links from Ubuntu's ISO file you cannot use FAT 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make the links but you can simply copy the content from the link target to the location of the link. Remember that a live system doesn't write data on its storage medium.

Comment: If i understood right: Both 'stable' and 'unstable' links as well as the targeting folder are all in the very same folder, so its pointless.

Comment: Why would it be pointless? There is 1 real folder in `./dists/` which has the adj. of the version name as its name. For example "trusty" or "precise". Then there are also the symlinks "stable" and "unstable" in `./dists/` which link to (for example) `./dists/trusty/`, so you need to delete "stable" and "unstable", make 2 more copies of `./dists/trusty/` which you then call `./dists/stable/` and `./dists/unstable/`. It doesn't matter that they all are in `./dists/`. If only one were there, one other was in `./boot/` and the last in `./install/` (for whatever reason), it would be just the same.

Comment: That explains procedure for them both. Thanks for the effort.